# Google Sheets Formula to Extract and Convert Currency from € or £ to USD

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, logical-operators, formulas

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Check the cell for `N/A` or `No`; if it has either of these then it should output `N/A` or `No`
2. Check the cell for either `£` or `€` or `Yes`; If it has one of these then it would continue to step 3. If it has `$` then it should repeat the same input as the output.
3. Extract currency from cell using: `REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\$\d+")` or `REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\£\d+")` (I assume that's the best way)
4. Convert it to $ USD using `GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")` or `GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")`
5. Output the original cell but replacing the extracted currency from step 3 with the output from step 4.

#### Examples: (**Original --> Output**)

- `N/A` --> `N/A`
- `No` --> `No`
- `Alt` --> `Alt`
- `Yes` --> `Yes`
- `Yes £10` --> `Yes $12.19`
- `Yes £10 per week` --> `Yes $12.19 per week`
- `Yes €5 (Next)` --> `Yes $5.49 (Next)`
- `Yes $5 22 EA` --> `Yes $5 22 EA`
- `Yes £5 - £10` --> `Yes $5.49 - $12.19`

I am unable to get a working `IF` statement working, I could do this in normal code but can't work it out for spreadsheet formulas.

I've tried modifying @Rubén's answer lots of times to including the `N/A` as it's not the Sheets error, I also tried the same for making any USD inputs come out as USD (no changes) but I really can't get the hang of IF/OR/AND in Excel/Google Sheets.

```
=ArrayFormula(
  SUBSTITUTE(
   A1,
   OR(IF(A1="No","No",REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[\£|\€]\d+")),IF(A1="N/A","N/A",REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[\£|\€]\d+"))),
   IF(
    A1="No",
    "No",
    TEXT(
     REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[\£|\€](\d+)")*
     IF(
      "€"=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "([\£|\€])\d+"),
      GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD"),
      GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")
     ),
   "$###,###"
   ) 
  )
 )
)
```

The above, I tried to add an OR() before the first IF statement to try and include `N/A` as an option, in the below I tried it as you can see below in various different ways (replace line 4 with this)

```
IF(
  OR(
    A1="No",
    "No",
    REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[\£|\€]\d+");
    A1="No",
    "No",
    REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[\£|\€]\d+")
  )
)
```

But that doesn't work either. I thought using `;` was a way to separate the OR expressions but apparently not.

## Re: Rubén's latest code 16/10/2016

I've modified it to =ArrayFormula(
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),

```
IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("$",A2),0),A2,IF(A2="N/A","N/A",IF(A2="No","No",IF(A2="Alt","Alt",IF(A2="Yes","Yes",
    SUBSTITUTE(
      A2,
      REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[\£|\€]\d+"),
      TEXT(
        REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[\£|\€](\d+)")
        *
        VLOOKUP(
          REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "([\£|\€])\d+"),
            {
             {"£";"€"},
               {GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD");GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")}
            },
        2,0),
        "$###,###"
      )
    )
  )))))
,"")
 )
```

This fixes:

- Blank cells no longer throw #N/A
- `Yes` only cells no longer throw #N/A
- Added another text value `Alt`
- Changes the format of the currency to 0 decimal places rather than my original request of 2 decimal places.

As you can see in the image below the two red cells aren't quite correct as I never thought of this scenario, the second of the two values is staying in it's input form and not being converted to USD.

[image]

Comment: GoogleFinance and REGEXTRACT are not available in Excel by the other hand, please add the formula that you tried.

Comment: I see your point but the same would essentially apply to Excel, just using `Find()` or `InStr()` and `Len` mixed with `Left()`/`Right()`/`Mid()` and as for the currency exchange they could just add a new web query to the likes of yahoo finance or use the `Excel Currency Converter` add-in. As for the formula, I've tried plenty but I can't get get a hang of the IF statements.

Comment: The guidelines requires askers to keep track of their research (see [ask]). I didn't found questions keeping an exhaustive research track, so with at least one, your question should be fine, I think.

Comment: Considering Excel and Google Sheets in a question that requires non-common functions make the question too broad and it could be closed for that reason.

Comment: Rubén, even the likes of `=IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\$"), "Dollar", IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\£"), "Pound", IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\€"), "Euro", ""), ""), "")` doesn't seem to extract the correct currency. It just throws up `#N/A` so I can't even get past that simple step; I assume I'm meant to be using `IF(OR())` or maybe `IF(AND())` but I can't work how I would use them in this scenario.

Comment: Looks that you should go on step back to learn how to use IF and the logical functions AND and OR. Try something simple first before trying something complex. To learn about the syntas of the functions, look for the specific page about them on [Lists of Functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén that's the thing, I have tried to learn them but can't get the hang of them in unfamiliar scenarios.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125832/discussion-between-ruben-and-ryflex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Direct answer

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("$",A1:A6),0),A1:A6,IF(A1:A6="N/A","N/A",IF(A1:A6="No","No",
    SUBSTITUTE(
      A1:A6,
      REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6, "[\£|\€]\d+"),
      TEXT(
        REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6, "[\£|\€](\d+)")
        *
        VLOOKUP(
          REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6, "([\£|\€])\d+"),
            {
             {"£";"€"},
               {GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD");GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")}
            },
        2,0),
        "$###,###.00"
      )
    )
  )))
 )
```

Result

```
+---+------------------+---------------------+
|   |        A         |          B          |
+---+------------------+---------------------+
| 1 | N/A             | N/A                |
| 2 | No               | No                  |
| 3 | Yes £10          | Yes $12.19          |
| 4 | Yes £10 per week | Yes $12.19 per week |
| 5 | Yes €5 (Next)    | Yes $5.49 (Next)    |
+---+------------------+---------------------+
```

## Explanation

### OR function

Instead or using OR function, the above formula use nested IF functions.

### REGEXTRACT

Instead of using a REGEXEXTRACT function for each currency symbol, a regex OR operator  was used. Example

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6, "[\£|\€]\d+")
```

Three regular expressions were used,

- get currency symbol and the amount `[\£|\€]\d+`
- get the amount `[\£|\€](\d+)`
- get the currency symbol `[(\£|\€])\d+`

### Currency conversion

Instead of using nested IF to handle currency conversion rates, VLOOKUP and array is used. This could be make easier to maintain the formula assuming that more currencies could be added in the future.

Comment: Rubén, The `N/A` isn't a Google sheets error in my examples, I tried to edit your array formula to accommodate it with an `OR` statement in the first `IF` statement but that doesn't work. I've tried it in every way possible even: `OR(IF(C109="No","No",REGEXEXTRACT(C109, "[\£|\€]\d+")), IF(C109="Unknown","Unknown",REGEXEXTRACT(C109, "[\£|\€]\d+"))),` *Also* If the currency is USD, then it should just copy itself rather than throw up `#N/A` Edited main post to show this.

Comment: @Ryflex: Add what you tried to the question. Also add examples for USD on the input data.

Comment: I've modified your last formula and fixed a few things with it, it also helps me understand the nested if statements. It does however have one issue remaining. I've edited my topic to include the latest changes and the issue.

Comment: @Ryflex: Regarding the "new" scenario,  I think that you should post that as a new question.