# Google Sheets Formula to Extract and Convert Currency from EUR or GBP to USD

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I'm trying to get a formula to convert a series of currency strings into USD so that I have some currencies that are the same.

For now I am only doing it for EUR, GBP and USD however later I will expand it to more currencies.

---

I have a formula that is currently able to do the following:

#### Normal

- ->  (Blank to Blank)
- `Yes` -> `Yes`
- `No` -> `No`
- `Alt` -> `Alt`
- `N/A` -> `N/A`

#### €

- `Yes €100` -> `Yes $110`
- `Yes €200 (Current)` -> `Yes $219 (Current)`
- `Yes €300 NA` -> `Yes $329 NA`
- `Yes €400 Next` -> `Week  Yes $439 Next Week`
- `Yes €500 5 RE` -> `Yes $549 5 RE`

#### £

- `Yes £100` -> `Yes $122`
- `Yes £200 (Current)` -> `Yes $243 (Current)`
- `Yes £300 NA` -> `Yes $365 NA`
- `Yes £400 Next Week` -> `Yes $486 Next Week`
- `Yes £500 5 RE` -> `Yes $608 5 RE`

#### $ (USD)

- `Yes $100` -> `Yes $100`
- `Yes $200 (Current)` -> `Yes $200 (Current)`
- `Yes $300 NA` -> `Yes $329 NA`
- `Yes $400 Next Week` -> `Yes $400 Next Week`
- `Yes $500 5 RE` -> `Yes $500 5 RE`

---

## Problem:

It isn't however able to cope with the following:

- `Yes £600 - £700` -> `Yes $730 - $851`
- `Yes €600 - €700` -> `Yes $658 - $768`
- `Yes $600 - $700` -> `Yes $600 - $700`

Currently, the `€` EUR version and the `£` GBP lines will only convert the first value, I need it to convert both values into USD.

- `Yes £600 - £700` -> `Yes $729 - £700` (Note the $ for the first currency on the output and £ for the second currency on the output)
- `Yes €600 - €700` -> `Yes $658 - €700` (Note the $ for the first currency on the output and € for the second currency on the output)

---

#### Current Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),
  IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("$",A2),0),A2,IF(A2="N/A","N/A",IF(A2="No","No",
    IF(A2="Unknown","Unknown",IF(A2="Yes","Yes",
      SUBSTITUTE(
        A2,
        REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[\£|\€]\d+"),
        TEXT(
          REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[\£|\€](\d+)")
          *
          VLOOKUP(
            REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "([\£|\€])\d+"),
              {
               {"£";"€"},
                 {GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD");GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")}
              },
          2,0),
          "$###,###"
        )
      )
  )))))
,"")
 )
```

[Formulas Original Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066147/2487602)

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort regarding the specific problem, anyway, I posted and answer with some suggestions that could give you some direction.

Comment: My browser history shows otherwise, I browsed through google's spreadsheet function list and looked at every single function, I googled tons of things and I searched on stack overflow. Your suggestions did help, I'm currently looking to do it via the google apps script instead

Comment: I didn't said that you didn't research, I said the the question doesn't show. The site guidelines ([ask]) requires to keep track of the research efforts, I think that including a summary or even the highlights is enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Split the values, do the conversion on each part, then join the parts.

## Suggestions

### SPLIT and JOIN built-in functions

Use [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=es) to separate on " - ", do the conversion on each part, then use [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=es) the parts. For this approach I think that you should use auxiliary columns, before and after the conversion.

### Try REGEX built-in functions

REGEX functions allow the use of arrays as arguments

Example
A3: `Yes £600 - £700`

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A3, {"[\£|\€]\d+","- ([\£|\€]\d+)$"}))
```

Result

B3: `£600`
C3: `£700`

### Try Google Apps Script

Having a spreadsheet with complex formulas could make it be hard to main by one side because it's not possible to include comments on each part of the formula and could be very easy to make an unwanted change, by the other side, scripts allows the insertion of descriptive comments and has less chances to be changed by accident.